# In Prism 7 for Xamarin Forms, is there a way to get prior page in OnNavigatedTo handler

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism, prism-7

New to using Prism in Xamarin Forms:  INavigationAware gives me the OnNavigatedTo handler.  I want different behavior in this form depending on where we are navigating from.  Is there a way to get the prior page?

Specifically I have page A that opens page B (modal) if a certain condition is true.  However, if the back button is hit from page B, returning me to Page A, I don't want to open page B again. Rather, I want to go back to the prior page beneath Page A on the navigation stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well passing the Page would be in direct violation of MVVM design, as your ViewModel should have no direct clue about the associated View. That said all of the INavigationAware methods use NavigationParameters which means that you can pass some value that you can check for similar to the following:

```
NavigationService.NavigateAsync("ModalA", new NavigationParameters {{"reason", "foo"}});

public void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters navigationParameters)
{
    switch(navigationParameters.GetValue<string>("reason"))
    {
        case "foo":
            // Do Foo
            break;
        case "bar":
            // Do Bar
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it's not easy to pass parameters from the hardware or software back buttons.  I think you're right another design would be cleaner.  But I'm not sure if I agree that the navigation history should be inaccesible to the VM.  I see navigation as within the domain of the VM.

Comment: @scotru you're welcome to disagree all you want. The bottom line is that the ViewModel should never directly know about the View. While I can't remember if this is a 7.0 or 7.1 feature, the NavigationService does have an extension `GetNavigationUriPath()` which you could evaluate to determine where you came from

Comment: Yea, GetNavigationUriPath() returns the current path (after the NavigatedTo is complete)--not the previous path--so still can't tell where I came from.  I don't really care about the View--I'd be happy to know the ViewModel that navigated to me (in fact I'd prefer it).

Comment: You've gotten me thinking about this more.  Is Prism's NavigationService.GoBack method a violation of MVVM design if used in a view model (since it requires knowledge of the page navigation history)?  I've taken a step back and posted a new question related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52616823/mvvm-conditional-return-navigation-in-prism