# MVVM Conditional return navigation in Prism

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, prism

Here's the business problem I'm trying to solve:

Start with pages: Menu -> Activity -> Connect.

When the user navigates from Menu -> Activity, if there is a specific piece of hardware not connected, I want to immediately Navigate to the Connect page.

When back button is pressed on Connect page and there is still no device connected, we navigate back to Acitivyt.  But now I do not want Activity to navigate again to Connect (trapping them in a loop).  Rather I want to navigate all the way back to Menu.  Prism does not (that I can find) provide a way for me to know if I'm arriving at the Activity page from the Connect page or from some other location.

In reality, Activity may be navigated to from a number of different places in the program, when they hit back on Connect, I want them to return to whatever page they came from before Activity (not necessarily Menu).  What I'd like to know is how can I solve this conditional navigation problem in Prism?

Comment: You could use `ParentIdentifiers` to know where you are coming from.

Comment: Can you move the condition to `Menu`? So that tapping on `Activity` in `Menu` navigates directly to `Connect` if no hardware is available?

Comment: @Haukinger, yes, but the problem is that Menu is not the only page that may navigate to Activity  -- maybe I need to create some sort of navigation helper that all pages that navigate to Activity use?

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez That sounds like what I need. Is that a Prism feature?

Comment: Your `VM Base` from which your VM should inherit should have a `Guid?` that you can check whenever you want to. I don't know if there is something like this in Prism